# Change label text when selecting UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I have a class in which I define a CollectionView which I use as a custom TabBar. It has three cells in it, each representing another tab. When I select a tab (which is thus a cell of the CollectionView), I want to update the text of a label inside my view.

In tabs.swift (where all the magic happens to set up the custom tabbar), I added the following function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let uvController = UserViewController()
    uvController.longLabel.text = "Test"

}
```

In UserViewController, I call it like this:

```
let ProfileTabs: profileTabs = {

    let tabs = profileTabs()
    return tabs

}()
```

It shows all the tabs I want, but when I select it, the label doesn't update. However, when I perform a print action, it does return the value of the label:

```
print(uvController.longLabel.text)
```

This returns the value I defined when I set up the label, so I can in fact access the label, but it doesn't update as I want it to do. Any insight on why this is not happening?

Comment: is uvController the Custom UICollectionView you defined?

Comment: @EdisonLo No, uvController refers to the UIViewController containing all elements of my main view. So tabs.swift only refers to the TabBar, which is defined in UserViewController (see code above), which is 44px in height, and underneath is longLabel, also defined in UserViewController, which I want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line - `let uvController = UserViewController()` creates a new instance of `UserViewController` which is not on the screen. You need to reference the one already shown to the user. You can do something like this :

1. The fastest way. 
   Just pass the instance in `ProfileTabs` initializer. Something like this:

   ```
   class ProfileTabs {
       let parentViewController: UserViewController

       init(withParent parent: UserViewController) {
           self.parentViewController = parent
       }

       // and then change to :
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

           parentViewController.longLabel.text = "Test"

       }
   }
   ```
2. The cleaner way. Use delegates.

   ```
   protocol ProfileTabsDelegate: class {
       func profileTabs(didSelectTab atIndex: Int)
   }

   class ProfileTabs {
       weak var delegate: ProfileTabsDelegate?

       init(withDelegate delegate: ProfileTabsDelegate) {
           self.delegate = delegate
       }

       // and then change to :
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           delegate?.profileTabs(didSelectTab: indexPath.item)

       }
   }
   ```

   And then in `UserViewController`

   ```
   extension UserViewController: ProfileTabsDelegate {
       func profileTabs(didSelectTab atIndex: Int) {
           longLabel.text = "Test"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Trying to implement this but it throws this error: 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer - I am already overriding init to set my frame (override init(frame: CGRect) in which I call super.init(frame: frame)). Can I combine these two?

Comment: Yes, you can. Or you can pass the `parentViewController`/`delegate` via a property after initialization. You will have to make it public though.

Comment: How would I do that - pass it as a property after initialization? I can't seem to get it to work. When I tried to combine them, it threw a coupe of errors as well. Have never done this before so I'm taking some wild guesses as to how to do it correctly, but I keep doing it wrong obviously.

Comment: `let pTabs = ProfileTabs()` and then `pTabs.delegate = self`, or `pTabs.parentViewController = self` depending which route you take.

Comment: I still get two errors: _Property 'self.parentViewController' not initialized at super.init call_ on super.init(frame: frame) and _Cannot assign value of type '(UserViewController) -> () -> (UserViewController)' to type 'UserViewController'_ on pTabs.parentViewController = self

Comment: I got it to work. I had to make the parentViewController an optional. Then the tabs are declared in my function setupViews(). Works as expected now! Thank you a 1,000 times!

Answer (score 2):

```
let uvController = UserViewController()
```

This line is the problem.

You instantiate the a new UserViewController instead of referencing to your current UserViewController, so that the label is not the same one. You can print(UserViewController) to check it out, the address should be different.

My suggestion for you can define a protocol in Tabs.swift and make your UserViewController a delegate of it, to receive the update action.

In the same time, `let ProfileTabs: profileTabs` is not a good naming convention as well, usually custom class should be in Capital letter instead of the variable.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense and it puts me on the right track, thank you! I have also changed the ProfileTabs  to profileTabs and vice versa - I normally name everything like you mentioned, but made a mistake on this one apparently. Thank you!